# get click event on subview on main uiview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a view which has scrolling images + paging. I have added these images on a UIVIEW and have added this UIView to  main view. I want to detect click event on images within scrollview and handle them in main view.

How do I do it?

Please help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can solve the problem with a gesture recognizer.

```
// In the view controller where you create the subviews
// (not sure from your question, but I think you are adding image views to a scroll view

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake...];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewTapped:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Now, this will get called when the image view gets tapped

```
- (void)imageViewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr {

    UIImageView *theImageViewThatGotTapped = (UIImageView *)gr.view;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Gesture simple one

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake...];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewTapped:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

And call the selector method and do what ever u want..

Answer (score 2):

Personally, rather than adding a `UIImageView`, I add the images as a `UIButton` and set the image for that button. Then you link the touch up inside event to your method as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry i have no time for write code.

set different tag to all Images save all images in array. And then in touchbegin set frame for and check using tag.